# Browser back button in a silex application

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

In my application made with Silex, if I go to the address "/logout", I leave my admin panel and go to my login form. However, if I press the back button on the browser, I go back to the previous interface. Although the session is already disabled and when you touch something you are redirected to /login.

This is my security settings:

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'admin' => array(
        'pattern' => '^.*$',
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/auth/login',
            'check_path' => '/login_check',
            'always_use_default_target_path' => true,
            'default_target_path' => '/auth/redirect/'
        ),
        'anonymous' => true,
        'logout' => array(
            'logout_path' => '/auth/logout',
            'target_url' => '/auth/login',
            'invalidate_session' => true
        ),
        'remember_me' => array(
            'key' => $app['remember_me_key'],
            'lifetime' => $app['remember_me_lifetime'],
            'remember_me_parameter' => '_remember_me'
        ),
        'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
            return new User\UserProvider($app);
        }),
    ),
```

How I can control that when you try to go back, if the session is over, you will be redirected to the login form?

**Edit**

I thought about adding the following headers:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

But how I can add this, or something similar, to the template login.twig?

Comment: In every page at the starting, you check for session variables. So on going back also, the session will be verified. @lvanpg